# ¿Cómo escribo sobre una posibilidad, con futuro o con subjuntivo?

Tags: subjuntivo, conjugación

Usualmente, cuando escribo algo en español, pienso en cómo lo escribiría en inglés y se lo doy a google translate.  Es posible que esto sea una idea mala, pero lo hago.

Ahora, escribí esto:

> Es posible que no **podré** completar todos los pedidos.

Mi oración inglés es:

> It is possible that, I won't be able to complete all the orders.

Cuando le doy esto a google translate, me sugiere:

> Es posible que no **pueda** completar todos los pedidos.

En esta oración, la palabra "*poder*" es subjuntiva y presente, en mi oración la palabra es indicativa y futura como la de la oración inglés.  ¿Cuál es correcta?

Comment: Google tiene razón (nota que Google lo hace correctamente con *pueda* pero pusiste aquí *puede*).  Si te parece necesario subrayar la posterioridad de la acción, puedes usar perífrasis: *es posible que no **vaya** a poder completar*, pero normalmente el contexto es suficiente.

Answer (score 1):

### It is possible that, I won't be able to complete all the orders.

está traducida correctamente como

> Es posible que no *pueda* completar todos los pedidos.

Respecto a usar el tiempo futuro, podrías decir

> Probablemente, no vaya a poder completar todos los pedidos